# javascript bookmark script for filling text boxes not working for React page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a bookmark on my Chrome browser with the following javascript code. So I don't need to type username/password for the login web pages.

```
javascript:(()=>{
    let f=(s,v)=>document.querySelector(`[id$="${s}"],[name$="${s}"],[type$="${s}"]`).value=v;
    f('password','....');
    f('username','...')
})()
```

It works on most of our login pages. However, on one of the login pages created with **React**, the username and password text boxes (html input) do fill in, but the value is not submitted when clicking the login button. Unless I make some editing in the username and password text box (e.g., by adding a space and then delete it).

Is it a way to avoid manually editing the text boxes? (it seems the script needs to trigger some events like keyup?)

HTML input:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="username" disabled="" class="login-input input" type="text" value="">
```

[image]

---

Tried the following code and it still behaves the same.

```
javascript:(()=>{
    let f=(s,v)=>{
        x=document.querySelector([id$="${s}"],[name$="${s}"],[type$="${s}"]);
        x.value=v;
        x.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", {target: {value: v}}))
    };
    f('password','....');f('username','....')
})()
```

Comment: Depends on what kind of event your input field in react is listening to.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in react, there are 2 ways to get the value of what is in the input and use it in the app.

1. Uncontrolled components where they use `ref` and just check ref which should be automatically updated when value changes.
2. Controlled components, where they hold the value in state, and they set the state on an `onChange` event like so:

```
const [val, setVal] = useState("") // initial value of empty string
return <input value={val} onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)} />
```

If the code is setup like the second case, we may need to simulate an `onChange` event ourselves in order for the state to update.

We can try modifying the script like so:

```
javascript:(()=>{
    let f=(s,v)=>document.querySelector(`[id$="${s}"],[name$="${s}"],[type$="${s}"]`).dispatchEvent(new Event("change", {target: {value: v}}))
    f('password','....');
    f('username','...')
})()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question with the information (from Chrome browser inspect). I don't have the React source code of the page.

Comment: BTW, will your code works for non-React page too?

Comment: Tried the following code `javascript:(()=>{let f=(s,v)=>{x=document.querySelector(`[id$="${s}"],[name$="${s}"],[type$="${s}"]`);x.value=v;x.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", {target: {value: v}}))};f('password','....');f('username','....')})()`. But it still got "Please enter a correct username and password" until I manually edit the inputs.

Comment: what happens if you just put focus on the textbox and focus out, and then try submitting(without modifying like adding space or anything), does it go through?

Comment: It still got the same error after I clicked each inputs and then click the login button.